# C++, I want to search one character in string, and output all words which contain this character

Tags: c++, string

I have one string for example, " Today is Monday " if the user types "o", the program must output "Today and Monday" because they contain "o".

My code is this but its not working its only search substring.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#define size  100

int main()
{
    char str[size];
    char searching_string[size];

    cout << " Enter String : ";
    cin.getline(str,100);

    cout << " String : " << str;

    cout << " Enter Search String : ";
    cin.getline(searching_string,size);

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << strstr(str,searching_string);

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not [tag:c] and it's not functional programming.

Comment: sorry its my first time to ask question on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Besides of the Quality of this Question. 
I think `strchr()` is what you are looking for.

[Link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/)

Hang on.